# Ethernet port doesn't work anymore

Tags: network

I was using my iMac 27" 2010, doing some work online. From one instant to another, internet stopped to respond. Unable to ping the local router, I initially believed it crashed. However, the rest of my home network was fine.

I'm now forced to use a WiFi connection to connect to the internet. Tried to boot Windows, it dosen't detect the wired network connection too.

A bad way to be forced to change a 1500€ machine.

What do you suggest?

Comment: Have you tried changing the cable? That's a lot cheaper than a new iMac...

Comment: Yes, the cable is fine. The port on the router is fine.

Comment: Did you try to run the network assistant from within Preferences/Network?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to reset your network settings to default?

1. Turn off your WiFi and unplug all network connections
2. Go to `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration`
3. Take a backup of the `preferences.plist` by renaming the file to `preferences.plist.bak` (just in case)
4. Reboot and a new preferences-file will be automatically recreated

... and by so your network settings will be restored to the default.
Don't worry, it's all about settings, not stored data (like names of networks) will be erased.

Comment: Ok, i'm gonna try this. However since that i already tried to boot Windows, how exactly could that help? Thank you anyway.

Comment: Do you use Bootcamp or some kind of virtualisation software?

Comment: I use vmware but Windows was loaded as a the native OS via bootcamp, naturally. Just tried to reset the network config, without any success. Maybe I will buy an USB Ethernet adapter... I will check some latency specs.